# Android: How to make TextView editable?

Tags: android

How can I allow user to edit a `TextView`? Of course, I can use `EditText` instead, but I don't know how to customize it and also I've read in Android documentation that `TextView` can be editable. So I tried this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="80sp"
          android:text="MyText"
          android:editable="true"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:cursorVisible="true"/>
```

But it still looks like common `TextView`. Does anyone know what I have missed? Or, may be, how to customize `EditText` for it look like `TextView`: without borders and background?

Comment: You can use EditText instead of.

Comment: What the problem to use with EditText? you can change EditText interface by applying style

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I know you don't want to use an `EditText` but it's really easy to make it look like a `TextView`.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/Id"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
 </EditText>
```

You can also use `android:background="@null"`.

**Edit:**

The `TextView`'s `editable` param *does* make it editable (with some restrictions).

If you set `android:editable="true"` you can access the `TextView` via the D-pad, or you could add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to be able to gain focus on touch.

The problem is you cannot modify the existing text, and you cannot move the cursor.
The text you write just gets added before the existing text.

Comment: Right.  In fact, EditText inherits from TextView.  The biggest changes being that they made it handle touch events and put in a background.  Remove the background (and possibly screw with the padding a bit) and it's a TextView that the user can edit on touch.

Comment: Ok, it's accepable, but I still wonder why TextView can be declared as "editable"

Comment: If you set editable to true in xml, Eclipse gives you the following warnings: *android:editable is deprecated: Use an <EditText> to make it editable - Attribute android:editable should not be used with <TextView>: Change element type to <EditText> ?*

Comment: Moreover, TextView documentation affirms: "A TextView is a complete text editor, however the basic class is configured to not allow editing; see EditText for a subclass that configures the text view for editing.". See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: This is not the right way to do it.its best done progammatically.Add the instructions to your textview inside your code instead of making a textview editable using EditText...check out this link,,,,,,.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html

Comment: @RileyManda I don't think you know what you're talking about, however if you have a better answer please post it and help the community.

Comment: @Beniot Bertoli will do

Answer (score 9):

You can fake a editable Textview. You just have to hide the textview when you touch it (make it "clickable"), replace it with an EditText, and display it again when the edit is over.

Answer (score 9):

You can make your TextView editable by adding these lines

```
tv.setFocusable(true);
tv.setEnabled(true);
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

TextView defines all capabilities found on EditText, but doesn't have built-in support to them. Some main differences on EditText:

a) **Method getDefaultEditable() returns true**. This is only a mark that defines this subclass as editable.

b) **A movement method**. Is an object that control the cursor behavior (position, backward/forward moves - that may change in some languages, etc). In opposition, TextView just returns null, because is not cursor anyway.

c) **Method CharSequence getText()**. TextView returns a single String for that. EditText uses a specific char sequence implementation (Editable) that represents a mutable text buffer.

Because that, we can't think about TextView like a restrained EditText. TextView sketch the editoring interface, but not implement itself.

If you need a text component that you can switch off editing sometimes, you are looking for the EditText component.

Answer (score 3):

```
    tv.setCursorVisible(true);
    tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    tv.requestFocus();
    tv.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: when you're answering question please be kind to refer other answers. this answer is already given.

Comment: Malith, his answer is different from the one already provided. Both having 4 lines doesn't make them the same lol

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to your problem by creating the **TextView** programmatically

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context, null, android.R.attr.editTextStyle) {
    @Override
    public boolean getDefaultEditable() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

**OR IN XML**

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView_ID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:style="@android:attr/editTextStyle"
android:editable="true"/>
```

Enjoy!